# LinerLayout inside a relative layout is not visible

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

here is my code , when i edit it inside eclipse and it shows the middle layout containing two buttons radia and television in graphical layout window. but when i run it on phone or tablet the middle layout disappears and is not shown.any kind of help please here is my code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android1:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android1:id="@+id/outerLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:background="@drawable/header" >

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/logout"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android1:background="@drawable/logout_a"
        android1:onClick="logoutClick"
        android1:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android1:background="@drawable/search_a" />

    <LinearLayout
        android1:id="@+id/innerlay"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android1:gravity="center"
        android1:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/television"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:background="@drawable/television_a"
            android1:onClick="television" />

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/radio"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:background="@drawable/radio_b"
            android1:onClick="radio" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: what does hierarchyviewer says ?

Comment: i have not checked hierarchy view, but the graphical layout shows everything as i have placed each control in it.

Comment: `layout="@layout/activity_main"` share this layout? also know us *hierarchyviewer*.

Comment: @user1828730 Post activity_main.xml file code so we can help you more.

Comment: that include tag is not the part of the code , i have edited it now sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here in relative layout

Instead of

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

you can use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

i hope this will work...

Comment: and your hierachy is wrong the hierarchy should be linear --relative--close relative -- close linear..

Comment: there is linearlayout closing tag in the end , but that is missing here in when i copied the code..

Comment: the closing tag was present but incorrectly indented (and hence invisible)

Answer (score 0):

The layout which you are saying is invisible, set its layout_height or layout_width property or both to "fill_parent".

I hope this work as i got mine working.